# Stack Remote - Free Android app dedicated towards Stack Exchange sites!

Tags: app, android

### Screenshots

[image] 
[image] 
[image] 
[image] 
[image] 
[image] 
[image]

### About

Stack Remote is a dedicated Android app for the Stack Exchange sites like Stack Overflow, Server fault, Gaming, User Experience, Super User, etc.

The app uses the read-only API provided by Stack Exchange to browse view questions and answers on any of the sites from Stack Exchange. Users can also follow tags from particular sites and get notified when a new questions is posted on a followed tag. Users have the option to authenticate their accounts and check for inbox messages.

Since this is a read-only app, you always have the option to go to the website link, where you can post questions, answers or comments.

#### License

Free [Google Play](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Play) app. No fee, no hidden charges.

#### Download

You can download the app from Android Market as "Stack Remote" or by following the link below
[Google Play download link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.b5d.android).

#### Platform

Currently released version 1.0 for Android.

Version 1.0 for iPhone is currently in development.

### Contact

Developed by: Karan

UI/UX by: Pratheep

Comment: Wow, I am developing a similar one, beat me to it.

Comment: Building a ios version? If so i cant wait to see that up in app store and check it out. My ios would take more time. :)

Comment: Nice app! I'm a Developer Advocate on the Android Developer Relations team at Google. If you're interested, I'd like to offer some advice on how you can improve the app even more.

Comment: Hi Reto, Many thanks for the comment. Much appreciated. I would really like to hear from you, regarding the valuable advice once I push the next update(1.2.0) which I'm currently working on. Kind Regards

Comment: is it open source?

Comment: @Blankman. the code at this moment in time is still closed-source but I hope to release it once I reach a stable version on all platforms like iOS, Windows and Android. Regards.

Comment: @Karan I'm getting the authorization step hanging on my Sony Tablet S using both the default browser and Firefox - it just hangs there saying `Authorizing Application`

Comment: @BiggAl I'm sorry about that, but we are working on an alternative way to enable connecting accounts to the app. It should be available on the next update which is due this week.

Comment: @KaranM: It would be awesome if you embedded a QR code linking to the app in your post.

Comment: Are you gonna run this app through the blackberry-android port. I would love to get this on my PlayBook.

Comment: Have you run the update for that authorization bug yet? This app looks promising but I've been unable to use it :( Just tried reinstalling it too

Comment: I like the UI, but I'm still have the same authorization bug issue as those above. It really takes away from the app as a whole.

Comment: Where can I find the APK?  My Android device supports neither the Market nor Google Play.

Comment: When I tried `connect account`, the browser stayed in a page saying `Authorizing Application`, and nothing happened then, my account was still not connected. My device is Samsung P1000 with Android 2.3.3

Comment: @KaranM would love to see the source code too... I'm not too familiar with oauth, so it could help save me a lot of trouble :P

Comment: How about making the app more ICS themed? I feel the current look of the app is very out of sync with the current Android UI Developer Guidelines. http://developer.android.com/design/index.html If you'd make your code open-source, other would be able to contribute and make it even better. +1 for a great app nonetheless.

Comment: Look forward for Stack Remote new version to use SE API 2.1 to add ability to write

Comment: @Deqing I have the same problem!.. cannot autorize the application on my android HTD Wildfire. :(

Comment: I'm having trouble authorizing as well.

Comment: I have the same forever `Authorizing Application` problem with this app on my Note II.

Comment: @KaranM I've also got the `Authorizing Application` problem, any news on that update?

Comment: Same here any update on the Authorization Problem?

Comment: are you still working on your website at http://blur5design.com/ ?

Comment: direct link maybe? im currently living without play store

Comment: Finally got an Android phone and installed Stack Remote - what an amazing UI!

Comment: I can't connect my Google account. It keeps on reloading the page.

Comment: having an option for download *other* than Google Play would be great. SlideME, Amazon etc. or just plain old download APK

Comment: BTW, I could not find it by searching "Stack Remote" in Google Play.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the links to the source and install website went dead. I'm keeping this for reference in case someone else gets inspired by this and creates a new, fresh script or app.

Answer (score 4):

I just downloaded android app from market, and tried to look around. And i realized that you keep recreating activity again and again. If you keep open activities enough, this app will realy generate memory overflow :D. (try it and you will need to use back button a lot to exit :)  ) 
And also too obvious and eye diturbing pixelerated UI designs. I hope you fix it. Because i like to keep in eye on stackoverflow on mobile.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. currently working on a holo ui with more features. should be available in the market soon..cheers